# How can I make a nice yellow button with text shadow?

Tags: html, css

I almost have a nice blue button but I want the background yellow and I want the text in center.

```css
#post3 {

width: 450px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* FF3.6+ */


    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #6db3f2), color-stop(50%, #54a3ee), color-stop(51%, #3690f0), color-stop(100%, #1e69de)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */


    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */


    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */


    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* IE10+ */


    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* W3C */


    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#1e69de', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */


    /*display: inline-block;*/
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /*width: 290px;*/
    height: 45px;/*
    font-size: 150%;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(109, 179, 242) 0%, rgb(84, 163, 238) 50%, rgb(54, 144, 240) 51%, rgb(30, 105, 222) 100%);
    background-position: initial initial;
    background-repeat: initial initial;
}
```

```html
     
    <div id="post3"> <a href="/ai">Loren Ipsum</a></div>
```

Can you please help me? I don't know how to center the text and I don't know how to apply a text shadow.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why don't you just assign the relevant css properties the values you want? And btw, `width = 450px:` must be `width: 450px;`.

Comment: @connexo Thank you for the help. That solved one problem of fixed width. Now I don't know how to get the color right of the background. The reason I got this far with CSS is more luck. I looked at twitter bootstrap's buttons and they were not as nice as you can do with a gradient. I can apply the font myself but I failed to center the text.

Comment: @Niklasinstockholm:Just change the color code according to your requirement.

Comment: Use `text-align: center;` and `text-shadow: ...`, text-shadow being assigned the shadow you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1kesuhug/1)

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(242, 227, 109) 0%, rgb(219, 238, 84) 50%, rgb(240, 231, 54) 51%, rgb(222, 222, 30) 100%);       
width:450px; /*It was width=450px; */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
#post3 {
    background: #ffcf32; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffcf32 0%, #ffff30 50%, #f7df27 51%, #ffdf89 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffcf32), color-stop(50%,#ffff30), color-stop(51%,#f7df27), color-stop(100%,#ffdf89)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffcf32 0%,#ffff30 50%,#f7df27 51%,#ffdf89 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffcf32 0%,#ffff30 50%,#f7df27 51%,#ffdf89 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffcf32 0%,#ffff30 50%,#f7df27 51%,#ffdf89 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffcf32 0%,#ffff30 50%,#f7df27 51%,#ffdf89 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffcf32', endColorstr='#ffdf89',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /*width: 290px;*/
    height: 45px;/*
    font-size: 150%;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(109, 179, 242) 0%, rgb(84, 163, 238) 50%, rgb(54, 144, 240) 51%, rgb(30, 105, 222) 100%);
    background-position: initial initial;
    background-repeat: initial initial;  
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
span.center-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  
  line-height:45px; 
}
#post3 a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 7px #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="post3"><span class="center-content"><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just copy and paste the code above you should see the yellow colored button with gradient effect. Have a look at the URL http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffcf32+0,ffff30+50,f7df27+51,ffdf89+100;Custom for creating the gradients on the fly.

This code coveres

1. Yellow gradient
2. Horizontally and vertically centered text
3. Shadow effect for the text on the button